# Horizontal tape Ticker in phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, ticker, yahoo-finance

I need to implement yahoo stock Horizontal tape ticker in phonegap. I am trying to find  solutions in internet but not getting any help. Any suggestions would be appreciate.